# Spring4 MVC multiparts

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring4 MVC and trying to upload a file along with some other input fields.

I added multipart resolver in spring xml and jackson converter

```xml
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
   <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
   <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf8" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
  <beans:property name="messageConverters" >
    <beans:list>
       <beans:ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In my form I have declared it as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and below is my ajax call

```js
var oemManuals = new FormData();
oemManuals.append("name",$( "#name" ).val());
oemManuals.append("description",$( "#description" ).val());

 if($('#url').val()){
  oemManuals.append( 'url', $( '#url' )[0].files[0] );
}

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/uploadManuals", 
    data:  oemManuals,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
```

In my controller I tried through `@RequestParam` and request but getting a `required paramerter name is null`. Though I see the parameters are present

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadManuals", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<OEMManuals> uploadManuals(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                                    @RequestParam MultipartFile url, 
                                                    HttpSession session) throws IOException{
```

All the values are null.

Can someone please suggest if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have specified a parameter 'url' in the controller.

```
@RequestParam MultipartFile url
```

So there must be a parameter named url in your ajax call like below

```
 url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/uploadManuals?url=value",
```

Comment: i appending the url to formdata,                                                           if($('#url').val()){
  oemManuals.append( 'url', $( '#url' )[0].files[0] );
}

Comment: just to add i am able to see the data in content disposition.

Comment: not in the content as per your controller signature it is expecting the parameter 'url' along with the actual url.